# Print out the duplicates and the amount of duplicates in ruby arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

if I gave you an array:

`['apples', 'bananas', 'apples','apples','apples', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'troll']`

and said:

Print me out the name of an each items and how often they appear, such that the out put was:

```
apples 4
bananas 1
cat 1
dog 2
troll 1
```

How would you do this, it seems simple, but to me it is stumping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as below :-

```
array = [
         'apples', 'bananas', 'apples','apples',
         'apples', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'troll'
        ]

array.group_by(&:to_s).each do |k,v|
  puts "#{k} #{v.size}"
end
# >> apples 4
# >> bananas 1
# >> cat 1
# >> dog 2
# >> troll 1
```

Comment: Good that you used `to_s` as substitute for a method that returns itself.

Comment: @sawa Yes... as all are *strings*.. that's why I used. But if the *array* is a combination of different objects, then it wouldn't work. :-)

Comment: `Object#itself` will be coming soon.

Comment: @sawa Woow!! Where you found it ? Is this called *identity* method ?

Comment: Could also use `group_by(&:dup)`, but I prefer the old-fashioned `group_by {|e| e}` until we can say `group_by(&:itself)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That is inefficient.

Comment: @CarySwoveland HUmm.. Today I am so happy. You know why.. hehehehe